# Submitting requests

Tags: gtsummary

Thanks for the great package. I have a question about the bolding function. Would it be possible to add a function such as "bolding significant variables", if and when you have time ? I am not sure if this can be done currently. Many times we do not report p-values alone. I think it would be useful to bold levels/variables that are statistically significant (the point estimate, CI, and p-value). I did not know where to post such a request. I hope it is ok to do so here.

Have a great day !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have finer control over how the table is styled using the `modify_table_styling()` function. Example below!

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.7.1'

trial |> 
  tbl_summary(
    include = c(age, stage),
    missing = "no",
    by = trt
  ) |> 
  add_p() |> 
  modify_table_styling(
    column = label,
    rows = p.value < 0.8, # change this threshold to 0.05 for the standard levels of significance,
    text_format = "bold"
  ) |> 
  as_kable() # convert to kable to display on stack overflow
```

| **Characteristic** | **Drug A**, N = 98 | **Drug B**, N = 102 | **p-value** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Age** | 46 (37, 59) | 48 (39, 56) | 0.7 |
| T Stage |  |  | 0.9 |
| T1 | 28 (29%) | 25 (25%) |  |
| T2 | 25 (26%) | 29 (28%) |  |
| T3 | 22 (22%) | 21 (21%) |  |
| T4 | 23 (23%) | 27 (26%) |  |

<sup>Created on 2023-05-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Hi @Daniel.
If I have multiple tables, is it possible to do this change for all tables at once or do I have to add it after each table separately?

Comment: You could write a custom theme to do this, and set the theme once at the top of the script. But I honestly think that's much more difficult than just adding it to each table